# web camera resolution

Tags: resolution, webcam

How do I find out what max resolution etc my integrated web camera supports?
I'd like to get the information from the actual machine.

In the event the internet has to be the source, I've got a ThinkPad T500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent ThinkPads have standard UVC webcams which do not need any special drivers.  The one in yours is a 1.3MP one, which usually means 1280x1024.

The more recent Tx1x and Xx1x models (the T510 replaces yours) have 2.0MP cameras, which you can retrofit to yours.  I'm planning on doing this with my X200.  You can find them for around £30 on eBay.

Comment: thanks @jason. very good input, way past what I asked for, but exactly what I needed.